# Unix Date Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, datetime, unix

такой вопрос как мне из unix системы времени перевсти в наше время в проэкте django и вывести все это в шаблон?

[image: Вот так выглядит в шаблоне сайта]

[image: Вот это поле нужно переконвертировать в Datetime]

Это поле нужно переделать

Comment: Я когда-то делал подобную штуку, вроде этот ответ мне помог тогда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date

Comment: Не помогло, ошибку выдает

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю написать `templatetag` для перевода `timestamp` в удобочитаемый вариант даты/времени. [Здесь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) вы найдете оригинальную документацию по созданию собственных тэгов.

Для начала в корне вашего приложения (именно app, а не всего проекта), создайте папку `templatetags`. Внутри папки обязательно создайте пустой `__init__.py` файл. Здесь же создайте файл, где будет логика, например такой `timetags.py` и напишите то, что вы хотите видеть. Пример из моего проекта:

```py
# timetags.py

from django import template
import datetime
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def from_timestamp_to_datetime(timestamp):
    try:
        ts = float(timestamp)
        time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)
        if time.minute < 10:
            minute = '0' + f"{time.minute}"
        else:
            minute = f"{time.minute}"
        if time.month < 10:
            month = '0' + f"{time.month}"
        else:
            month = f"{time.month}"
        timestr = f"{time.hour}:{minute}, {time.day}.{month}.{time.year}"
    except ValueError:
        return None
    return timestr
```

После всего этого вы можете загрузить данный тэг на страницу написав в html коде такую строку `{% load timetags %}`.

А следующая строка выведет вам формат даты указанной в логике тэга:

```py
{{ timestamp_value|from_timestamp_to_datetime}}
```

Конечно же, кастомизировать вывод даты нужно в самой логике. В моем примере выводятся **часы:минуты, день.месяц.год**. Где минуты и месяцы имеют ведущий ноль, если они меньше десяти.

Comment: Спибо за ваш ответ, но я немного не понимаю как это адаптировать это всё под мой код, если у вас есть время помогите пожалуйта.

Comment: я написал все шаг за шагом. `Создайте папку..., создайте файл..., создайте второй файл.... загрузите в темплейт при помощи команды... вызовите с переменной, которая содержит timestamp`. Здесь полный мануал

Comment: Все сделал, выдает ошибку.

Comment: Какую ошибку вам выдает? Вам предложили вариант в комментариях, я дал вам рабочий вариант. Вы пишете: "ошибка". Как вы предлагаете, чтобы вам дали ответ? Что вы видеть-то хотите? Дайте описание ошибок или ожидаемый результат